# I have a dataframe with a column that is a vector. I want to get the last element and store it in a new column. How can I do it?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

what I have dataframe that looks like this

```
df>
    col1       col2
     1     c('a', 'b', 'c')
     2     c('r', 't')
     3     c('x', 'y')
```

What I want a dataframe that looks like this

```
df>
    col1       col2             col3
     1     c('a', 'b', 'c')      'c'
     2     c('r', 't')           't'
     3     c('x', 'y')           'y'
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput(df)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df$col3 <- sapply(df$col2,function(s) as.vector(s)[length(s)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(C = I(list(list("a","b"),list("a","b","c"))))
df$D <- sapply(df$C, function(x) x[length(x)])
```

**Output**

```
C D
1 a, b b
2 a, b, c c
```